# Dynamic form fields not sending values

Tags: javascript, php, forms

The value entered in field "term" arrives to test.php
but values in fields "AttrName" and "Attribute" does not, even without adding any more fields, addition of more fields works, but values are not sent.

Code:

```html
 <head>
    <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js' integrity='sha384-nvAa0+6Qg9clwYCGGPpDQLVpLNn0fRaROjHqs13t4Ggj3Ez50XnGQqc/r8MhnRDZ' crossorigin='anonymous'></script>
    <script src='https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/dynamic-forms-fields/js/dynamic-form.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action='test.php' method='post'>
    <input type='text' name='term' size='60' placeholder='term' required /><br />
    <div id='dynamic_form'>
    <input type='text' name='AttrName' placeholder='Attribute name' />: <input type='text' name='Attribute' placeholder='Atributte' /> 
    <a href='javascript:void(0)' id='plus'> &nbsp; +</a> 
    <a href='javascript:void(0)' id='minus'> &nbsp; -</a>
    </div>
    <script>
    var dynamic_form =  $('#dynamic_form').dynamicForm('#dynamic_form','#plus', '#minus', {
    // the maximum number of form fields
        limit: 10,
    });
    </script>
    <br />
    <input type='submit' name='submit' id='submit' />
    </form>
    </body>
```

**UNDATE**

test.php:

```
<?php
echo $term=$_POST['term']."<br />";
echo $AttrName=$_POST['AttrName']."<br />";
echo $Attribute=$_POST['Attribute']."<br />";
?>
```

Comment: What does `dynamicForm()` even do here, since `$('#dynamic_form')` doesn't find anything?  Can you demonstrate the state of the form when it's submitted, after it's been modified by this JavaScript?  Or maybe provide a runnable example to demonstrate?

Comment: in PHP I would run `print_r($_POST);` to see what is getting posted.

Comment: Please post your PHP.

Comment: @David, sorry I have copied the wrong name, now is fixed

Comment: The field names are generated like: `dynamic_form[dynamic_form][0][AttrName]`

Comment: @imvain2, it prints: Array ( [term] => TERM [dynamic_form] => Array ( [dynamic_form] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [AttrName] => THIS-ONE [Attribute] => ATTRIBUTE ) ) ) [submit] => SUBMIT )

Comment: @RobRuchte done

Comment: @AndrésChandía: If you run the code snippet in the question and observe the AJAX request in your browser's debugging tools, you can see that the values most certainly are being sent to the server.

Comment: @David, Ok, how should I collect them, see the ansewer to imvain2

Comment: Both answers below are correct, but you also need to add id attributes to your AttrName and Attribute inputs or dynamic-form.js will complain and only send one entry.

Comment: @RobRuchte, yes, you're right, I will try to find out how to do that! thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form seems to be correctly submitting the values,  however you are accessing the `dynamic-form` values incorrectly in PHP:

`dynamic-form` creates a nested array so you need to use the following reference:

```php
echo $AttrName=$_POST['dynamic_form']['dynamic_form'][0]['AttrName']."<br />";
echo $Attribute=$_POST['dynamic_form']['dynamic_form'][0]['Attribute']."<br />";
```

As your form is dynamically generated and there can be any amount of fields, you need to loop on `$_POST['dynamic_form']['dynamic_form']` e.g

```php
forEach($_POST['dynamic_form']['dynamic_form'] as $form) {
  echo $form['AttrName'];
  echo $form['Attribute'];
}
```

From @Rob Ruchte's comment:

Also add `id` attributes to your html for `dynamic-form` to work properly:

```html
<div id='dynamic_form'>
  <input type='text' id='attrName' name='AttrName' placeholder='Attribute name' />:
  <input type='text' id='attribute' name='Attribute' placeholder='Atributte' /> 
  <a href='javascript:void(0)' id='plus'> &nbsp; +</a> 
  <a href='javascript:void(0)' id='minus'> &nbsp; -</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through the `dynamic_form` array like this:

```
$dynamic_form = $_POST["dynamic_form"]["dynamic_form"];

foreach($dynamic_form as $row){
  echo $row["AttrName"];
}
```